# Use regex in Visual Studio 2012 search

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I know that are similar questions, but I want to find the any css classes inside files.

When I press CTRL+SHIFT+F in order to make a search in all files, I typed the following regex

```
(class="\w.*).+(title).+(").+
```

I want to match any class attrbiute which contains `title`.

Means, I want to find match for the following situations:

```
<p class="title">Test</p>
<p class="anotherCss title">Test1</p>
<p class="something title anythingElse">Test2</p>
```

but I don't want to match `title` attribute ! like:

```
<p title="test">Test3</p>
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Hint: if you want to find `title` inside a `class` attribute, then what you **don't** want to match when skipping characters is a `"` character. `.` matches `"`.

Comment: Means `(class=\w.*).+(title).+` ?

Comment: Is not working for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
class="[^"-]*title
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/y2XjzGbMAM-GJMQq)

Comment: It will match also `class="item-title"`